# Alpha anywhere: How to get all the data from the list so that I can access them using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, list

Using alpha anywhere. I have a list, say 'roles' and 'companies' filtered by user_code. I am using it offline so I need everything to be pre-populated while connection available. When Offline, I need to filter the list by company so that I can get the 'roles' based on the current company_session. Can anybody point me to the right way? Or at least can anyone teach me how to get the data from the A5W list and bring them to javascript accessible like javascript array, or JSON format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. too long on a computer. Alpha Anywhere actually have simplified this. In UX component method I found `getListData` method. It done exactly what I need!! at least I am one step ahead.

```
var data = {dialog.Object}.getListData('USERROLESLIST');
var dataJSON = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Then, the `JSON.stringify` give me the visual of the actual data in the list.